# Performance Index with Negative Weights

Tags: math

Let's say I have the below table and I want to calculate a performance index for each row. I assign a weight of 10 to **profit** values and -50 to **unit** values. I'm using a negative weight because I want rows with high units to hurt the performance index.

| Profit | Units |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 10 |
| 200 | 100 |
| 10 | 50 |
| 80 | 1 |

Using these weight values, I get the below index for each row (simply value x weight for each column and then add them together)

| Profit | Units | Index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `100 (100 x 10) = 1000` | `10 (10 x -50) = -500` | 500 |
| `200 (200 x 10) = 2000` | `100 (100 x -50) = -5000` | -3000 |
| `10 (10 x 10) = 100` | `50 (50 x -50) = -2500` | -2400 |
| `80 (80 x 10) = 800` | `1 (1 x -50) = -50` | 750 |

At this point everything works but let's say with these indexes I want to calculate share of each row. If the weights were all positive it would be easy. Simply add up each column and calculate the total index then divide the index of each row by the total index. But with negative weights that doesn't work. You can't just take the absolute value of each index either.
My first though is to adjust each index by the absolute value of the total index that way they all become positive. Then divide each index by the sum of all the indexes. This would look like the below.

| Profit | Units | Index | Adjusted_Index | Share |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `100 (100 x 10) = 1000` | `10 (10 x -50) = -500` | 500 | `500 + 4150 = 4650` | `4650 / 12450 = 37.35%` |
| `200 (200 x 10) = 2000` | `100 (100 x -50) = -5000` | -3000 | `-3000 + 4150 = 1150` | `1150 / 12450 = 9.24%` |
| `10 (10 x 10) = 100` | `50 (50 x -50) = -2500` | -2400 | `-2400 + 4150 = 1750` | `1750 / 12450 = 14.06%` |
| `80 (80 x 10) = 800` | `1 (1 x -50) = -50` | 750 | `750 + 4150 = 4900` | `4900 / 12450 = 39.36%` |

While this works, I feel like there must be a simpler way than this. Any thoughts are apricated.

Comment: There are many ways to summarize this information, but helping you pick a good one is impossible without knowing your goal. What do you intend to do with the output of this?

There's a second problem, which is that it's off-topic here. It's not even a math question, but more in the realm of analytics or data interpretation. I think the Cross-Validated site might possibly fit what you're looking for, but I don't use that site so may be wrong about that.